# deleting the database is not synchronized in another node

Tags: mariadb, galera, mariadb-10.4

I used this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mariadb-on-centos-7-servers)and I have 2 servers (nodes).

Everything works fine, the problem is when I stop MariaDB on both servers and then delete the database on the second node.
When I try to synchronize again, the second server does not recognize the database

I made some changes in selinux but it didn't work
After re-synchronization, it is possible to create a new database and it can be accessed on both servers

Comment: how many nodes are in the cluster ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen 2 nodes

Comment: Galare cluster MUST have a minimum of 3 nodes i.e 3,5,7,9. Galera work via split brain. read this : https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/weighted-quorum.html

Comment: @BerndBuffen The problem is not with the number of nodes, if the number of nodes is 3, 5 or 7, it is no longer possible to synchronize by shutting down MariaDB and then changing one of the databases.

Comment: Were you using SST?